# Imagemap: click to display text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, imagemap

I'm trying to display an image with clickable areas, which shows a different text description at the bottom of the image for each clickable area. This is the code I have:

Edit: I can't figure out how to get this code to display properly either, sorry :(

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<head>
 <style>
    a .img {
     border:none;
    }
    .caption {
     display: none;
        }

    .caption:target {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 510;
        text-align: centre;
        }

    body {
        background-color: #1e1e1e;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: Trebuchet MS;
        font-size: 16pt;        
        } 

 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="blahblah.png" usemap="#blahblah">
  <map name="blahblah">

  <area shape="rect" coords="XX,XX,XXX,XXX" href="#text1">
    <div class=caption id=text1>
        <u>display some text</u> 
        </div>
    <area shape="rect" coords="XX,XX,XXX,XX" href="#text2">
    <div class=caption id=text2>
        <u>display some other text</u> 
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly in Chrome, but my text will not appear in IE8. Can anybody tell me why, and maybe suggest a fix? Trying to avoid javascript because I know pretty much nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this does not work in IE8 is because you are using within your CSS the `:target` selector. This is a CSS3 selector which is not supported in IE8. See documentation: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp

An easy fix would be to use the external Javascript library: [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/).

This make it possible to use any CSS3 properties. Please keep in mind if you use this you also need to include jQuery.

Your HTML would look something like this:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<head>
<!-- CDN VERSION OF jQUERY, You can also download it --> 
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<!-- The rest of your HTML -->
```

If you just include those two scripts within your HTML, without any further modifications, your website will work.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work. I copied those scripts and put them in the head section. I set the 'src=jquery.js' but nothing changes

Comment: @A_Mac you have downloaded the selectivizr.js file, from their website, and you paste the source within the script files, like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js\selectivizr.js"></script>`??

Comment: I have. I just read the readme file attached to the downloaded and it says there is a bug with the :target pseudo class. Apparently it won't work with jQuery, but will work with Sizzle, so I'm going to try that